# gvim 7.4 on windows 7 - Multiple Line Match

Tags: vim

I am looking for a way to search or match multiple lines in gvim. I am using gVim 7.4 (32 bit) on Windows 7 (64 Bit).

Here's what I am trying to achieve.

Say I have text such as this:

```
20000000c9abdcef10000000c9abcdef
20000000c9ababefab10000000c9ababefab
20000000c9cdcded10000000c9cdcded
20000000112233aa10000000112233aa
some random text line here 
20000000c9abdcef10000000c9abcdef
20000000c9ababefab10000000c9ababefab
20000000c9cdcded10000000c9cdcded
```

I just need the lines highlighted which have the word "20000000c9abdcef10000000c9abcdef" followed by a new line and the word "20000000c9ababefab10000000c9ababefab" again followed by a new line and the word "20000000c9cdcded10000000c9cdcded".
I select the 20000000c9abdcef10000000c9abcdef, 20000000c9ababefab10000000c9ababefab and 20000000c9cdcded10000000c9cdcded by doing a Vblock select. Then I yank it, then I hit the "/" so that I am in the command search mode (I hope thats what its called). I then press Crtl+r which puts a " next to the / so it looks like /" and then I type " again. If I were to have a single line of text, it would get pasted there, but if I have multiple lines, the lines get pasted one after the other with a ^M between them. So this is how it would look:

```
~
~
~
~
/20000000c9abdcef10000000c9abcdef ^M20000000c9ababefab10000000c9ababefab ^M20000000c9cdcded10000000c9cdcded
```

The first four tildas are just to give the above output a gvim like look. 
Now when I hit enter, it does not search/highlight the three lines.

I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong. Would be extremely thankful if someone could help.

Sincerely,

pmu

Answer (score 1):

do this instead:

```
/apples\noranges\npeaches
```

**EDIT**

ok, if you really want to do that, you could first do yank as you have done, then:

```
:let @"=substitute(@",'\n','\\n','g')
```

then

```
/<c-r>"
```

create mapping if you do this very often.

Comment: Hi, I can do that however, what I had given above was just an example. what I need to do is able to Vblock copy and paste that and then search it. Thats because what I am searching for includes hex digits which are 16 bits long. I have edited the example above to reflect the same.

Comment: @pmu see EDIT in answer

Answer (score 0):

My [SearchHighlighting plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4320) extends the built-in normal mode `*` command to visual mode, and automatically translates the line breaks into the proper `\n` atoms. (The plugin page has links to alternative plugins that offer the same.)